# Arm64 project with x86 DLLs on Windows

Tags: dll, .net-6.0, arm64

I have a project that I'm publishing as ARM64 variant (along with x64 and x86) but users are getting an error when loading the app.

```
An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (0x8007000B)
System.BadImageFormatException
 at MS.Win32.PresentationCore.UnsafeNativeMethods.MilCoreApi.RenderOptions_ForceSoftwareRenderingModeForProcess(Boolean fForce)
 at System.Windows.Media.RenderOptions.set_ProcessRenderMode(RenderMode value)
 at Myapp.App.App_Startup(Object sender, StartupEventArgs e) in App.xaml.cs:line 156
 at System.Windows.Application.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
 at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(Object unused)
 at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
 at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

The line that triggers the issue has a call to the Util.dll to load and parse settings, which contains a bunch of `Type.GetType()` and `Activator.CreateInstance()` calls, but the exception is not triggered there.

My publishing settings are this:

[image]

[image]

When checking each published DLLs, I noticed that not all are ARM64:

- MyApp.exe (and other DLLs): Arm64
- MyApp.dll: x86 (this one is automatically generated)
- SharpDX.DXGI.dll: x86 (the only nuget package installed)
- Accessibility.dll: x86 (from .NET)
- mscorlib.dll: x86
- netstandard.dll: x86

As far as I understand, an ARM64 device should load x86 DLLs without issues.
Is that right?

How can I detect what's triggering this issue?

Comment: AFAIK arm64 devices have an emulation layer for x86, but you cannot mix arm64 and x86 binaries in the same process.

Comment: It's strange that it triggers inside the .NET class `RenderOptions` and not my code.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this?

Comment: @Dominique Yes, it was an issue with .NET 6, I ended up publishing with .NET 7 RC while they were fixing it, then I believe it was fixed in 6.0.8 or something like that.